# How to effectively garbage collect in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have a flash game that I'm building where I have an array keeping track of a bunch of power ups on the screen.  When the player goes an grabs one it needs to disappear from the screen (which is easy) but it also needs to be removed from the array so that collision detection loops don't become really cumbersome.  I tried using splice, but I keep get null reference errors, here's the relevant code.

```
public function collect():void {
            try {
                Main.powerUps.splice(index, 1);
                stage.removeChild(this);
            }catch (e:Error) {
                trace("Error in splice");
            }
        }
}
```

Then when I create my PowerUp object I pass it a parameter that gets assigned to index which is the length of the array of Power Ups at the time.  Can anyone see what's wrong with this code or (preferably) provide a more elegant solution?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elegant solution: use `indexOf()` and `splice()` together!

```
var index:int = Main.powerUps.indexOf( powerup );
Main.powerUps.splice(index, 1);
```

Where `powerup` is a reference to the object stored within the array `Main.powerUps`.

I also created a little class a while back that may be useful to you:

- https://github.com/MartyWallace/Lotus/blob/master/Lotus/lotus/utils/Set.as

It has a `.remove()` method so you can just do:

```
powerUps.remove(powerup);
```